# Using DocumentFormat.OpenXml and getting 'Cannot access a disposed object'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**Following Exception:**

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name' Wordprocessing

This is the function I am using to dynamically find and replace text:

```
public void FindAndReplace(WordprocessingDocument doc, string toFind, string toReplace)
{
    var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

    foreach (var para in paras)
    {
        foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
        {
            foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
            {
                if (text.Text.Contains(toFind))
                {
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace(toFind, toReplace);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Nothing to replace. [{toFind}] was not found...");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that `doc` is disposed before `FindAndReplace()` is called, probably because it is outside the `using` of the method that calls it? If that is the case remove the `using` and dispose the doc manually.